# How to select one radio button from dynamically created radio buttons?

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a situation to select one radio button from dynamically created radio buttons. I know it is possible with Radio group but still I am not able to do it because my situation is little different. Let me explain it.

I have a question like "A recent survey found that in British secondary schools" with 4 options like
A.

B.

C.

D.

All data coming from the server in json form. I have created the view dynamically with one question and four options with radio buttons. But what i am understanding is every row is new row and I am not able to select only one radio buttons from all radio buttons. Every button is selecting individually but I want to select only one radio button on which I click.

Any help would be appreciated.

you can see my view below:

[image]

My code is :

```
    LinearLayout linearLayoutForQuestions = (LinearLayout)   view.findViewById(R.id.questionsLinearLayout);
    linearLayoutForQuestions.removeAllViews();

    //set the questions for the user

    for (int ss = 0; ss < totalNoOfQuestions.size(); ss++) {

        final List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("SELECT");
        TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        textView.setTypeface(typeface1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        String question = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getQuestions();
        String questionNo = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).QuestionNo;
        textView.setText("Question " + questionNo + " " + question);

        //linearlayout and set data inside it
        LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(activity);
        parent.removeAllViews();
        parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


        int optionSize = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getOptions().size();
        for (int s = 0; s < optionSize; s++) {


            //children of parent linearlayout
            LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(activity);
            layout2.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layout2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

            String optionNo = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getOptions().get(s).getQuestionOptionNo();
            TextView textView1 = new TextView(activity);
            textView1.setText(optionNo);
            textView.setTextSize(15);

            final RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(activity.getApplicationContext());
            radioButton.setId(s);
            radioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.settings_background_ripple);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams pa = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            pa.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
            radioButton.setLayoutParams(pa);


            radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    int checkedRadioButtonId = buttonView.getId();
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "hit it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            String questionOption = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getOptions().get(s).getQuestionOption();
            TextView textView2 = new TextView(activity);
            textView2.setTextSize(15);
            textView2.setText(questionOption);

            layout2.addView(textView1);
            layout2.addView(radioButton);
            layout2.addView(textView2);

            parent.addView(layout2);

        }

        linearLayoutForQuestions.addView(textView);
        linearLayoutForQuestions.addView(parent);


    }
```

Comment: You have to add radio button in RadioGroup.

Comment: Create a RadioGroup before for loop and add radio button in for loop.

Comment: okay will try it, do you have any working demo , I tried radio group as well but can't get any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on it from a while and finally I find the way how to do it , posting my answer to let others take idea from it. I make it work by taking the array of Textview and Radiogroup outside the inner for loop.

Thank you everyone for the assistance. Happy Coding:)

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutForQuestions = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.questionsLinearLayout);
    linearLayoutForQuestions.removeAllViews();

    totalNoOfQuestions = readingTests[countReadingTest].getQuestion();



    //set the questions for the user
    for (int ss = 0; ss < totalNoOfQuestions.size(); ss++) {

        groupNo = ss;
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add("SELECT");
        TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
        textView.setTextSize(15);
        textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        textView.setTypeface(typeface1);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);

        String question = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getQuestions();
        String questionNum = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).QuestionNo;
        textView.setText("Question " + questionNum + " " + question);

        //linearlayout and set data inside it
        LinearLayout parent = new LinearLayout(activity);
        parent.removeAllViews();
        parent.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        parent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        final int optionSize = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getOptions().size();
        final RadioButton[] radioButton = new RadioButton[optionSize];
        int size = totalNoOfQuestions.size();
        final RadioGroup[] radioGroup = new RadioGroup[size]; //you can also create in xml
        radioGroup[ss] = new RadioGroup(activity);
        radioGroup[ss].setId(ss + 100);
        radioGroup[ss].setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL)ø;

        //this textview is for the optionsNo like A,B,C,D
        final TextView[] textView1 = new TextView[optionSize];

        LinearLayout layoutOptionsNo = new LinearLayout(activity);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        layoutOptionsNo.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layoutOptionsNo.setWeightSum(optionSize);
        layoutOptionsNo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        layoutOptionsNo.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        layoutOptionsNo.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


        LinearLayout layoutOptions = new LinearLayout(activity);
        layoutOptions.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f));
        layoutOptions.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        layoutOptions.setWeightSum(4);
        layoutOptions.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        //inner loop for the options for every single question
        for (int s = 0; s < optionSize; s++) {

            String optionNo = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getOptions().get(s).getQuestionOptionNo();
            textView1[s] = new TextView(activity);
            textView1[s].setText(optionNo);
            textView1[s].setTextSize(15);
            textView1[s].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams pa = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            pa.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            pa.weight = 1;
            textView1[s].setLayoutParams(pa);

            String questionOption = totalNoOfQuestions.get(ss).getOptions().get(s).getQuestionOption();
            radioButton[s] = new RadioButton(activity);
            radioButton[s].setId(s);
            radioButton[s].setText(questionOption);
            radioButton[s].setTextSize(15);
            radioButton[s].setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
            radioButton[s].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.settings_background_ripple);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams pa2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f));
            pa2.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
            pa2.weight = 1;
            radioGroup[ss].setLayoutParams(pa2);
            radioGroup[ss].addView(radioButton[s]);
            layoutOptionsNo.addView(textView1[s]);


        }

        radioGroup[ss].setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                int originalId ;
                int id = group.getId();{
                     originalId = id-100;
                }
                questionNo = totalNoOfQuestions.get(originalId).getQuestionNo();
                optionNo = totalNoOfQuestions.get(0).getOptions().get(checkedId).getQuestionOptionNo();

            }
        });

        layoutOptions.addView(layoutOptionsNo);
        layoutOptions.addView(radioGroup[ss]);
        parent.addView(layoutOptions);

        linearLayoutForQuestions.addView(textView);
        linearLayoutForQuestions.addView(parent);

    }
    boolean showOptionHint = totalNoOfQuestions.get(0).OptionList;
    LinearLayout linearLayoutForOptions = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.optionsLinearLayout);
    linearLayoutForOptions.removeAllViews();
    if (showOptionHint == true) {
        //dynamic creation of options under the quesiton layout
        List<ReadingTest.QuestionBean.OptionsBean> questionOptions = readingTests[countReadingTest].getQuestion().get(0).getOptions();
        for (int ss = 0; ss < questionOptions.size(); ss++) {
            String options = questionOptions.get(ss).getQuestionOption();
            String optionsNo = questionOptions.get(ss).getQuestionOptionNo();
            TextView textView = new TextView(activity);
            textView.setTextSize(18);
            textView.setTypeface(typeface);
            textView.setTextColor(view.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            textView.setText(optionsNo + ". " + options);
            linearLayoutForOptions.addView(textView);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **RadioGroup** as below:

```
      LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout); //layout defined in xml main activity layout

                    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this); //you can also create in xml

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    );
                    layout.addView(radioGroup, p);

 /*radio button 1*/

                    RadioButton radioButtonView1 = new RadioButton(this);
                    radioButtonView1.setText("RadioButton1");
                    radioButtonView1.setOnClickListener(this);
                    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView1, p);
/*radio button 2*/
                    RadioButton radioButtonView2 = new RadioButton(this);
                    radioButtonView2.setText("RadioButton2");
                   radioButtonView2.setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);    
                    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView2, p);
/*radio button 3*/
                    RadioButton radioButtonView3 = new RadioButton(this);
                    radioButtonView3.setText("RadioButton3");
                   radioButtonView3.setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);
                    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView3 , p);
/*radio button 4*/
                    RadioButton radioButtonView4 = new RadioButton(this);
                    radioButtonView4 .setText("RadioButton4");
                   radioButtonView4.setOnClickListener(mThisButtonListener);
                    radioGroup.addView(radioButtonView4 , p);
```

Here you can select only one option out of multiple

As you required how to select value, then please use following code snippet:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId)
       {
           radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //text related to option selected.


       }
   }
   );
```

Thanks

Comment: this suits fit if you have only one row but in my case I have multiple rows and each row has a radio button

Comment: not yet, actually you are right but i think i am not able to explain my situation properly.

Comment: if you see my code , two for loops are running simultaneously. One for total no of questions and inside for loop is working for options for a particular question which is 4 in my case. Now real problem is we need to initialialize radiogroup inside the inner for loop otherwise it will show an error "child has already parent please remove it" something like this but that thing make radiogroup an individual radio group for every row which is option in my case. I hope you got my point of view.

Comment: I stuck to this situation from the last few days, I am working on it continuously but can't find any solution for now

Comment: Are you still facing any problem? for your old problem you should improve your view hierarchy.

Comment: Not now, Thank you,  yes you are right I have changed my view hierarchy and it worked and I posted my answer below as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Sandeep Singh Bandral

You have done a great Work, Why you are doing such a heavy work
Just Create a Radio Group Work and assign a Id ,and call **setOnCheckedChangeListener**

You can see here

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override 
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // find which radio button is selected 
                if(checkedId == R.id.answer1) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer1", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if(checkedId == R.id.answer2) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer2", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else if(checkedId == R.id.answer3) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer3", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }  else { 
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Answer4", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } 
            } 

        });
```

In the place of Toast ,DO YOUR STUFF

**Test Case:if you don't know how many radio buttons for each Question, you can see the below code over here**

```
radiogroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
         void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
              for(int i=0; i<radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
                   RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
                   if(btn.getId() == checkedId) {
                        String text = btn.getText();
                        // do something with text 
                        return; 
                   } 
              } 
         } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is rather old, but I just had the same problem. The solution is to change the state of RadioButton after adding it to RadioGroup by addView(). I guess this is also what BAKUS tried to say by his sample code.

copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27900625/1936201)